# Do iphone push notifications send the actual sound data to play, just a filename, or is it handled by the app?

Tags: iphone, push-notification

And, does it cache it locally?

I ask because I am wondering if it's possible to change the sound of a push notification via SSH, replacing an app sound.

My question is specifically about how the API for push notifications works. Does it send a .caf (aiff) binary file for the phone to play each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no file being sent. You can add a sound name for a file that's stored in your app which you want to be played when the notification arrives. See the [Apple Push Notification Service Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW10) for further assistance.